# how to connect amazon rds mysql in iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am making an iOS app for which I have made the RDS mysql on amazon any idea how to connect the amazon RDS in iOS.

```
<?php
// we connect to example.com and port 3307


define("HOST", "dbinstance.jjjjj.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com");



define("USER", "test"); // Replace the ??'s with your database user login name
define("PASSWORD", "test"); // Replace the ??'s with your database user's login password
define("DB", "test"); // Replace the ??'s with your database name



$connection = mysql_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
$database = mysql_select_db(DB) or die(mysql_error());


?>
```

Comment: are you able to connect to local MySQL ? what you have tried?

Comment: yes I am able to connect using razor sql

Comment: hey can you please tell me what is razor sql and how to use it?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Mobile applications should never connect directly to your database server — doing so is a security risk, as it allows any user with the database credentials (that is, any user who downloads your application!) to connect to your database and read or modify any data without restriction.

An example of the havoc that can be caused by an architecture like this can be seen here, where a game developer had their game's online high scoring system and level editor destroyed when someone discovered that it was working this way:

http://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?noseen=0&threadid=2803713&pagenumber=258#post398884189

Create a web service which implements the necessary operations for your database, including access controls, and have your iOS application connect to and interact with that.

Comment: not I have not connect the iOS app to interact i am also looking to make webservice in php and get the data and operations but any idea how to make webservice with rds amazon

Comment: That's altogether too broad of a question to answer. There are many ways to go about that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comments ,Need to clarify that ..for now you can consider amazon rds is is same as your local database residing remotely,

1. you have to learn how to make php webservices first (not with rds amazon - it is one of distributed relational database service by Amazon.com)
2. than how to call that `php webservice` from iOs and
3. than just changing the DB connection `url` to the url which points to the amazon rds

Comment: I have done all the things calling php web service from iOS but it does not call the amazon db

Comment: post some code so that some one will able to identify where you stuck..connecting to rds is as simple as connecting to local database just have to change url,username,password

Comment: Posted code above please check it gives error Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110